# Genetics example with huge dimensional data

Tags: biometrics, large-data

I am looking for a real example of huge dimensional contingency tables, where, says, the number of rows and columns are thousands or millions. And the two random variables are ordinal (not nominal).

Is there any problem like that with sparse data? Says, we need to test the independence of two ordinal random variables X and Y in contingency tables where X or Y or both of dimension 1000 (1000000) and the input of the tables contains many cells with no observations?

I think that there may be some example in biology but I have no knowledge of it. Could anyone suggest one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question (these statistical terms are somewhat unfamiliar to me); however, one example of the data you seek might be transcriptomic data. The term "transcriptomic data" refers to measurements of the amount of RNA present in the cells of an organism. The axes of datasets like this are usually Gene (the gene which coded for that particular strand of RNA) by cell (the type of cell in the body from which the measurement was taken, e.g. heart, lung) by time (the point in time at which the cell was measured).

Unfortunately, the cell axis is not an ordinal axis but a nominal one. The other two axes are definitely ordinal. I suppose this is also a 3-dimensional tensor rather than a 2-dimensional matrix.

There are about 20,000 genes, and as our sequencing technology improves, the time axis can obviously grow very large.

This kind of data is typically *very* sparse. Not only do cells tend not to "express" [1] every gene, but we also suspect that sometimes the amount of RNA is too low to reliable measure it! This leads to interesting statistical problems wherein one needs to model both sparsity and low measurement counts!

The [wikipedia page on RNA-Seq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA-Seq) is an OK introduction. Moreover, if you're interested in the fusion of biology and math and computer science, you might find the lectures at [Models Inference and Algorithms](https://www.broadinstitute.org/scientific-community/science/mia/models-inference-algorithms) interesting, in particular you might like Kharchenko's talk "From one to millions of cells: computational challenges in single-cell analysis"!

[1] the expression "express a gene" means that the cell actually transcribes the gene into the corresponding RNA rather than ignoring it

Comment: Thank you so much, Daniel. I will have a look at your suggested links. Cheres.